# Monitor changes to DOM after JS script has been executed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, awesomium

As per question title, I am using Awesomium and need BEFORE and AFTER 'snapshots' (for want of a better word...) of the DOM to see the side effects a JS script has on the DOM. Basically, the scope here is to analyse the changes which the script made to the DOM after it has been executed by comparing it to the DOM before the script was executed.

Any approaches/reading material would be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the webpage once with js disabled and once without, and see the differences between those.

Comment: It would be better if this was comment to help improve the question, this is not an answer. You can either remove this and make it a comment or extend this answer to explain what the OP should do depending on the results/differences.